# Mat_<float> to OutputArray

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I try to pass a `Mat_<float>` as the destination for `cv::projectPoints`. Whenever I do this at runtime `_OutputArray::create` complains, that the type is *fixed* (`fixedType()` and `fixedSize()`).

Sadly the doc does not really explain these notions let alone describe what obstacles one has to jump over to use instantiate `OutputArray` (which is a highly problematic converter class).
Could someone shed some light about the antics of OpenCV and how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OutputArray` constructor that takes a `Mat_<T>` sets the `FIXED_TYPE` flag, since it is predetermined (it's `float` in your case). Since that implies a single-channel matrix and `projectPoints` wants to create a two-channel output, it fails. Use `Mat_<Vec2f>` or something equivalent.

Contrary to what vasile said, you *can* use `Mat_<T>` and also `Matx` (which has both fixed size and type) as an OutputArray (there are explicit constructors for `Matx` and `Mat_`, it's just that those constructors set flags that some things can't be changed, so functions that do try to change them will fail).

Comment: Thanks. Finally figured it out. The thing that tripped me up the most (besides the flag stuff) was _OpenCV_s handling of dimensions. And their excessive `cv::Mat` implementation.